# Cannot create a solution version There should be updates to at least one dataset after last active solution version with training mode set to FULL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

I am having an AWS personalize solution with 3 successful solution versions trained with trainingMode = "FULL" using both AWS console and AWS SDK python. However when I tried to create a new solution version with trainingMode="UPDATE" as shown in the code below:

```
import boto3
personalize = boto3.client('personalize')
personalize.create_solution_version(solutionArn = solution_arn, trainingMode = "UPDATE")
```

I've got back the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: InvalidInputException
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateSolutionVersion operation: There should be updates to at least one dataset after last active solution version with training mode set to FULL.
```

Anyone experiencing this issue, is there anything I miss to be able to train with an UPDATE mode?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `trainingMode="UPDATE"` is to process new items added to the items dataset (via [PutItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_UBS_PutItems.html) or a [bulk upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/bulk-data-import.html)) as well as impression data for new interactions added to the interactions since the last `FULL`/`UPDATE` training. The new items and impressions are used to update the exploration feature for solutions created with the [aws-user-personalization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-new-item-USER_PERSONALIZATION.html) recipe. That is, to bring in new/cold items for exploration and to adjust probabilities for existing cold items in further exploration. Note that `UPDATE` only brings in new items and impression data and does **not** retrain the model.

Therefore, if there are no dataset updates since the last `FULL`/`UPDATE`, there is no value in creating a new solution version with `UPDATE`.

Finally, keep in mind that Personalize [automatically updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/native-recipe-new-item-USER_PERSONALIZATION.html#automatic-updates) solution versions created with the aws-user-personalization recipe every two hours **at no cost**. This essentially does an `UPDATE` for you.

> With User-Personalization, Amazon Personalize automatically updates the latest model (solution version) every two hours behind the scenes to include new data without creating a new solution version. With each update, Amazon Personalize updates the solution version with the latest item information and adjusts the exploration according to implicit feedback from users. This allows Amazon Personalize to gauge item quality based on new interactions for already explored items and continually update item exploration.

If you create a solution version with `UPDATE`, you will be charged for the server hours to perform the update. Practically speaking, the only time you would need to manually create a solution version with `UPDATE` is when you do not want to wait for the next automatic update.